# How to make a .desktop file that launches python script in virtualenv?

Tags: linux, command-line, python, desktop

I have an application (it is cura, locally built) that i launch from command line with the following commands:

> cd my/cura/folder
>
> source venv/bin/activate
>
> PYTHONPATH=../lib/python3/dist-packages ./cura

How can i do the same form desktop file?

This is .desktop file i have made:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cura
GenericName=Slicer application
Comment=Prepare model for 3d printing
MimeType=model/stl;application/prs.wavefront-obj;application/vnd.ms-3mfdocument;text/x-gcode
Icon=cura-icon
Type=Application
Categories=3DGraphics;GUIDesigner;Graphics
Keywords=Slicer
Path=/home/kurvivor/Development/cura
Exec=source venv/bin/activate;cd cura-build/build/inst/bin; PYTHONPATH=../lib/python3/dist-packages ./cura
Terminal=true
```

However, all i get when trying to launch is "there was an error launching the application. When i go to the path i have set and execute same command i have put in exec, application launches fine.

Answer (score 0):

the PYTHONPATH enviromental variable needs to include the complete path

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cura
GenericName=Slicer application
Comment=Prepare model for 3d printing
MimeType=model/stl;application/prs.wavefront-obj;application/vnd.ms-3mfdocument;text/x-gcode
Icon=cura-icon
Type=Application
Categories=3DGraphics;GUIDesigner;Graphics
Keywords=Slicer
Path=/home/kurvivor/Development/cura
Exec=source venv/bin/activate;cd cura-build/build/inst/bin; env PYTHONPATH=complete/path/lib/python3/dist-packages ~/cura
Terminal=true
```

Comment: Sadly, does not work